# Get number of done items and total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to powerbi, sorry if the vocabulary is incorrect.
i have a datatable with this structure (simplified):

| Project | Epic | US | US done (1 if done) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | E1 | US1 | 1 |
| P1 | E1 | US2 | 0 |
| P1 | E1 | US3 | 0 |
| P1 | E2 | US4 | 1 |
| P1 | E2 | US5 | 1 |
| P2 | E3 | US6 | 1 |
| P2 | E3 | US7 | 1 |

"US done" tells me if the user story is done (1) or not (!= 1).
An epic is done if all associated user stories are done.

I am trying to get a visual of the number of Epic done per project, for example a table (based on the previous example):

| Project | Epic done | Total number of epic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 1 | 2 |
| P2 | 1 | 1 |

I calculated the total number of US:
total_us = COUNT(US)

and the number of US that are done
total_done_us = CALCULATE( COUNT(US) , US Done = 1 )

And then i calculate the difference between total_done_us and total_us:
Epic done = if(total_us - total_done_us =0, 1,0)

but it does not takes the epics into account, only the total of user stories.
I tried using a table or a matrix visual, but i do not success in having only the project name and the total of epic done per project and the total of epic per project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it has been solved:

```
Total US = DISTINCTCOUNT(SampleData[US])

Total US - Done = CALCULATE([Total US],SampleData[US done] = 1)

Total Epic = DISTINCTCOUNT(SampleData[Epic])
Total Epic - Done = COUNTAX(FILTER(GROUPBY(SampleData,SampleData[Epic]),[Total US] = [Total US - Done]),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it also be true that if there exists more than zero User Stories in an Epic that are not done, then the Epic is not done?

If your hierarchy is Project--(1,many)--Epic--(1,many)--User Story

then an Epic is only done if all of its User Stories are done. And a Project is done when all of its Epics are done.

```
US per Epic = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL('Projects'),[Epic]=MAX('Projects'[Epic])))

Completed US = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL('Projects'),[Epic]=MAX('Projects'[Epic]) && 'Projects'[US done (1 if done)]=True))

Epic Complete = ([Completed US] = [US per Epic])
```

Yes, you could likely do all of this in one measure, but it's much easier to debug if you do it a step at a time.